# How can I use scanf using the debugger in Atmel Studio?

Tags: c, debugging, embedded, scanf, atmelstudio

When I debug the program line by line until the scanf statement is reached, the IDE brings up a Disassembly tab that does not improve the situation in any way. How do I enter a key into the program once the scanf statement is reached when debugging a program???

code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRA = 0x00; //PORTA = 0x00;
    DDRB = 0xFF; //PORTB = 0x00;

    typedef enum {
        firstkey,
        secondkey,
        dooropens,
        }doorstate;

    doorstate state = firstkey;
    char secretkey;
    while (1) 
    {
        switch(state) 
        {
            case firstkey:
                scanf("%c", secretkey); //?????
                if (secretkey == '#')  {
                    PORTA == 0x01 << 3;
                    state = secondkey; 
                }
                else 
                    state = firstkey;  
                break;
            case secondkey:
                scanf("%c", secretkey);//?????
                if (secretkey == 'Y')  {
                    PORTA = PORTA | 0x02;
                    state = dooropens;
                }
                else 
                    state = firstkey;  
                break; 
            case dooropens:
                PORTB = 0x01;
                if (PORTA == 0x80) {
                    state = firstkey;
                    PORTB = 0x00;
                }
                break;
            default:
                state = firstkey;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The disassembly is probably because you are stepping *into* rather then *over* the library function.  The library function source is not available to the debugger in this case, so it has no choice but to show you the assembly.

Use step-over, and the function will behave normally and accept input and control will return to the debugger *after* the function returns.